# how to group by duplicate Field in Array List : ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I had problem with nested aggregation in Elasticsearch. I have mapping with nested field:

```
"Topics":{"type":"nested","properties":{ 
    "CategoryLev1":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}, 
    "CategoryLev2":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}} }}
```

After index Document:

```
"Topics": [
                  {
             "CategoryRelevancy": "1.0",
                     "CategoryLev2": "Money",
                     "CategoryLev1": "Sales"
                  },
                  {
                     "CategoryRelevancy": "2.0",
                     "CategoryLev2": "Money",
                     "CategoryLev1": "Sales"
                  },
                  {
             "CategoryRelevancy": "1.0",
                     "CategoryLev2": "Electrical",
                     "CategoryLev1": "Product"
                  }
               ]


    "Topics": [
                  {
             "CategoryRelevancy": "1.0",
                     "CategoryLev2": "Money",
                     "CategoryLev1": "Sales"
                  },
         {
           "CategoryRelevancy": "2.0",
                     "CategoryLev2": "Methods",
                     "CategoryLev1": "Sales"
                  },
                  {
            "CategoryRelevancy": "1.0",
                     "CategoryLev2": "Engine",
                     "CategoryLev1": "Product"
                  }
               ]
```

As you see, in my nested array I have two Topics, which have Duplicate key and Value field Then I  make such query:

```
{
   "size": 10,

   "aggregations": {
      "resellers": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "Topics"
         },
         "aggregations": {
            "topicGroup": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "Topics.CategoryLev1.keyword",
                  "size": 10
               },
               "aggregations": {
                  "Subtopic": {
                     "terms": {
                        "field": "Topics.CategoryLev2.keyword"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then I get following result which has group by with topic Category

```
{
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "resellers": {
         "doc_count": 6,
         "topicGroup": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "Sales",
                  "doc_count": 3,
                  "Subtopic": {
                     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                     "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                     "buckets": [
                        {
                           "key": "Money",
                           "doc_count": 3
                        },
                        {
                           "key": "Method",
                           "doc_count": 1
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": "Product",
                  "doc_count": 2,
                  "Subtopic": {
                     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                     "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                     "buckets": [
                        {
                           "key": "Electrical",
                           "doc_count": 1
                        },
                        {
                           "key": "Engine",
                           "doc_count": 1
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But I Want to result Like this

```
"buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "Sales",
                  "doc_count": 2,
                  "Subtopic": {
                     "buckets": [
                        {
                           "key": "Money",
                           "doc_count": 2
                        },
                        {
                           "key": "Method",
                           "doc_count": 1
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": "Product",
                  "doc_count": 2,
                  "Subtopic": {
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                           "key": "Electrical",
                           "doc_count": 1
                        },
                        {
                           "key": "Engine",
                           "doc_count": 1
                        }]
            }
}]
```

Thanks in advance :)